# Declaring an array of buffers in C++

Tags: c++, buffer, opencl

I am currently learning OpenCL and to build several kernels you need a buffer for each function, so you need an array of buffers. How do you build such a data structure? Can someone give me an example of a buffer struct so I can just declare an array of those structs?

Comment: A buffer could be many things. You'll need to be more specific. What kind of buffers does OpenCL expect?

Comment: Maybe something like this: `typedef char buffer[200]; buffer many_buffers[10];`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the C++ binding you could use vectors instead of raw arrays.

So you could store your buffers in a data-structure like :

```
std::vector<cl::Buffer>
```

Comment: Thank you for taking this seriously. I will definitely implement this in the next stage of development.